# Sitecore: Statistics on sitecore domain users

Tags: authentication, statistics, sitecore

I'm working with Sitecore 8 Update 2.
I'm looking for a way to get some statistics on how many sitecore users are logged in ( over time, not just right now).

Mainly i would like to see if the actual amount of people working on the system is close to the maximum amount of users allowed by the license. Otherwise a company might be seriously overpaying.

Is there already an out of the box solution or a module available for this ?

Comment: There is wide range of counters under Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.AnalyticsTrackingCount namespace. You could try to use them for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you visit this page:

`<your-domain>/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser`

It will give you a list of all the currently logged in CMS users. That page is a SPEAK application and has a datasource called `ActiveUsersDataSource`. In the code, this datasource uses the `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` property to get a list of all the sessions.

So if you just want a list, the KickUser page should be enough. If you want to run a report you can use the `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` property as a start. You could use that to write a report with Sitecore Powershell Extensions pretty simply.

Answer (score 1):

Log files usually contain audit information about login / logout. E.g.:

6140 13:57:33 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\djanjicek): Login
... 
7512 14:02:57 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\djanjicek): Logout

With Sitecore Log Analyzer you should be able to filter your log files on the audit trails.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx

If you need a web based solution then you could write an admin page that reads all log files and outputs the required lines in a timely fashion.

Comment: Hej, i started on your solution first as this would give me statistics about previous days / weeks. Unfortunately it didn't work because the log only shows a logout if the users actually did the effort to log out. And nut just close their browser. Without being able to be sure when a users logged out the information isn't very trustworthy.

Comment: I think it will be very hard to track that kind of event. Sitecore doesn't know that somebody closed their browser or turned off the computer without logging out first.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try this:

```
var x = Membership.Providers["sql"].GetNumberOfUsersOnline();
```

where "sql" is you membership provider name defined in configuration.